# How to put space and special character in datatable column in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want get datatable column as `Authorization Area`, `Test Fees [AED]`,But iam ending with column name as below

```
  dt.Columns["AUTH_PRIOD_AREA"].ColumnName = "Authorization Area";
  dt.Columns["Test_FEES"].ColumnName = "Test Fees [AED]";
```

trimming space and get `Authorization`,`Test`.how toget full name

Comment: Where are you getting those truncated names because if I bind that table to a GridVIew it shows correct headers?

Comment: Why are you using a DataTable here? Why does it mater to you if the column names have a space or not?

Comment: i am pushing in to an excel file from datatable by using EPPlUS library,not to asp.net gridview

Comment: If I export a DataTable into EPPlus it show the headers correctly. The problem is not with the column names having spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is becuase you cannot change teh column name to include spaces, this is the same idea behind why there are no spaces in SQL column names. If you are looking for the proper way to name these columns you would have to use either camelCasing or use underscores (_) to recognize spaces.